# display data from database group by transaction_code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my `database` I create table name `orders` where the `structure` is  `transaction_code`, `date`, `customer_name`, `product_description`, `quantity`, `total_quantity` all field have data.

In my previous activity I use `while loop` to display data from the table and it works ok,
in this situation i would like to group all rows have same `transaction_code`

image below show my database structure with data

[image]

Comment: You can just say `select * from orders where transaction_code = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from orders group by transaction_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this purpose.